# How to fix "ABAP INNER JOIN"

Tags: abap

i'm trying to get a inner join from two select sentences but it doesn't work, what i am doing wrong?

i cant work with internal tables because inner join doesn't permit it.

```
clear: it_spfli.
  refresh: it_spfli.

  select 
    spfli-cityto
    spfli-cityfrom
    into TABLE it_spfli from(select spfli-cityto COUNT( * )from spfli group by spfli-cityto) as t1
    INNER JOIN(select spfli-cityfrom COUNT( * )from spfli group by spfli-cityfrom) as t2
    ON t1-cityto = t2-cityfrom.
```

i expect a table of more frequency city to and city from order by city to with table `spfli`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The expression "doesn't work" is meaningless, please describe the exact symptom: I guess there is a syntax error by the compiler, which message? Please have a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to better ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Moreover, please use the format options so that your question can be read easily.

Comment: Kindly also redescribe the aim of your SQL query. We don't understand what you mean with "i expect a table of more frequency city to and city from order by city to with table spfli". For example, you calculate the number of occurrences of each city but then do nothing with it. And you expect some order, but don't include any ORDER BY clause. At best, give a sample SPFLI with 3-5 rows and show what you want to calculcate from that. At best also include the real life question you want to answer, e.g. "which city has most incoming flights, and from where?".

Comment: You should have a look at the command `FOR ALL ENTRIES`

Answer (score 0):

First of all i don't think you are doing the right SELECT to get what you want. 
I answer this question from the technical perspective. You can use [WITH](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abapwith.htm).

```
WITH +spf1 AS (
  SELECT spfli~cityto AS cityto, COUNT(*) AS count FROM spfli GROUP BY spfli~cityto ) ,

     +spf2 AS (
  SELECT spfli~cityfrom AS cityfrom , COUNT(*) AS count FROM spfli GROUP BY spfli~cityfrom ) ,

     +spf3 AS ( 
  SELECT s1~cityto, s2~cityfrom FROM +spf1 AS s1 INNER JOIN +spf2 AS s2
      ON s1~cityto = s2~cityfrom )

SELECT * FROM +spf3 INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result).
```